Solve the differential equation $ y_n^{\prime \prime}(r) + \frac{1}{r} y_n^{\prime}(r) - \frac{n^2}{r^2} y_n(r) = 0$
I would like to solve the differential equation
$$
y_n^{\prime \prime}(r) + \frac{1}{r} y_n^{\prime}(r) - \frac{n^2}{r^2} y_n(r) = 0,
$$
I thought to start by trying a solution of the form $y_n(r) = r^m$. Substituting $y_n(r) = r^m$ into the differential equation, we compute the first and second derivatives:
$$
y_n^{\prime}(r) = m r^{m-1}
$$
and
$$
y_n^{\prime \prime}(r) = m (m-1) r^{m-2}
$$
Now substituting $y_n(r) = r^m$, $y_n^{\prime}(r) = m r^{m-1}$, and $y_n^{\prime \prime}(r) = m(m-1) r^{m-2}$ into the differential equation, we get:
$$
m(m-1) r^{m-2} + \frac{1}{r} (m r^{m-1}) - \frac{n^2}{r^2} r^m = 0
$$
Simplifying each term:
$$
m(m-1) r^{m-2} + m r^{m-2} - n^2 r^{m-2} = 0
$$
Combining like terms:
$$
[m(m-1) + m - n^2] r^{m-2} = 0
$$
Factoring out $r^{m-2}$, we obtain the characteristic equation:
$$
m(m-1) + m - n^2 = 0
$$
Simplifying the quadratic equation:
$$
m^2 - m + m - n^2 = 0
$$
$$
m^2 - n^2 = 0
$$
This factors into:
$$
(m-n)(m+n) = 0
$$
Thus, the solutions for $m$ are:
$$
m = n \quad \text{or} \quad m = -n
$$
Therefore, the general solution to the differential equation is a linear combination of the two independent solutions $r^n$ and $r^{-n}$:
$$
y_n(r) = C_1 r^n + C_2 r^{-n}
$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.
Is my solution correct?
Even if it turns out to be correct, I don't like that I arrived at this solution 'by trial and error'. Can someone solve this equation in a different way? Thanks in advance.

This trial and error method is a standard way to solve ODEs. Don't feel bad about it.

@eyeballfrog: Thank you! That's really encouraging to hear. The truth is that  I always hope to find a more brilliant solution :-)

@Moo thank you!
